# How to access RemoteParticipant video stream in webRTC, while using Twilio Video API

Tags: twilio, webrtc, twilio-api, recordrtc

I am using [TwilioVideo](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/javascript-getting-started) for video calling in a webapp. I am trying to record `remoteParticipant` audio and video and store it in a local drive.

Here is a link to my [sample app](https://sample-twilio-video.herokuapp.com/), you can open two browser windows with the same url & provide two different userNames, but same roomName and connect.

After the video call is established through Twilio API between local and remote participants, I tried obtaining the remoteMediaStreams using the below method but I get `undefined`. Can someone please advise how I can obtain `remoteParticiant` stream (audio + video).

`window.RTCPeerConnection.getRemoteStreams` -> `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The [`RTCPeerConnection` class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection) doesn't have a `getRemoteStreams` function, which is why that is `undefined`.

Instances of `RTCPeerConnection` may have a `getRemoteStreams` function, but in this application you do not have direct access to the instance of the `RTCPeerConnection` object being used by the Twilio Video SDK, so you can't call on it. Also, `getRemoteStreams` is also non-standard and deprecated in favour of [`getReceivers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCPeerConnection/getReceivers).

It looks like you are using this [Twilio Video example application](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-video-app-react). To get hold of the remote streams you will need to hook into the room's participants and their audio and video tracks. I recommend you take a look through the various components and hooks in the application to understand how to access the media streams for each of the participants.

Comment: RTCPeerConnection.prototype.getRemoteStreams exists, albeit as a legacy API.

Comment: Thanks @PhilippHancke, I've updated the information on that. I think in this case the OP was trying to call on `RTCPeerConnection.getRemoteStreams` which isn't a function.